# Display number of divs according to the window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example the below image is at initial window position.. 
[image]

When I will decrease the window size then the number of divs should change accordingly.
[image]

Edit : Each map represents a Div.

Comment: There is no simple solution for this, so you will have to show some of what you've done.  Additionally, are the divs always at a set width/height?  How much can they stretch to fit?

Comment: you have to need more clarification

Comment: Firstly the Each Div should have a width of 300px which is fixed. and the number of divs' will change according to the window size.

Comment: Take an array where you can define the no of divs you want to load, when the window size is >= some value. Then on windoe resize event display the no of div you declared in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get sizes of maps:

```
var maps = document.getElementsByClassName('.map');
for(var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++){
    var map = maps[i];
    var rect = map.getClientRects()[0];
    map.left = rect.left;
    map.top = rect.top;
    map.width = rect.width;
    map.height = rect.height;
}
```

On screen resize event, where you will check:

```
for(var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++){
    if(maps[i].left + maps[i].width > screen.width ||
       maps[i].top + maps[i].height> screen.height)
        maps[i].style.display = 'none';
    else
        maps[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

I have not tested, hope it works

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, use the [.resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) method to check whether the window has been resized, then calculate how many divs you want to display (which is the window size divided by your div size). To get window height and width:

```
var h=$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
var w=$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
```

You can use [.hide](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to nicely reveal the exact number of divs.